# Flask doesn't show UTC time with moment.js

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, momentjs

I want to get the current UTC time with flask so I wrote the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask import render_template
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
moment = Moment(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', current_time=datetime.utcnow())
```

The  `index.html` contains the following code:

```
<p>The local date and time is {{ moment(current_time).format('LLL') }}.</p>
<p>That was {{ moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True) }}</p>
```

When i run the application and refresh I get the following result:

```
The local date and time is.
That was
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your page source you'll see the contents are there but `span` tag has an inline `style="display: none"` CSS, which is hiding the content from actual view. To fix this, you need to include moment scripts into your `templates/index.html`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>FlaskMoment UTC Current Time</title>    
    {{ moment.include_jquery() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
</head>

<body>
    <p>The local date and time is {{ moment(current_time).format('LLL') }}.</p>
    <p>That was {{ moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True) }}</p>
</body>
```